# Why isn't my page working when the same when I view it on my phone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Here's a link my page: https://intense-bayou-64974.herokuapp.com/

I built it originally for PC, and then made adjustments with media queries and some jQuery code to adapt to a smaller scree size. It works well in my browser on my desktop PC when I resize the window, but as soon as I looked at it on my phone it had a white margin that took up half the screen real estate and none of my media queries seemed to take in effect.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Your issue is that your circles have a fixed width and height of 199px as well as use fixed offsets (in px). You need to use relative units for these values.

Comment: I'll update the question with the solution, so other's can benefit it, sorry there was just too much which could have been wrong and then someone would have complained that I posted too much irrelevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It the green circles–I can view your site in chrome and 'scroll left' and see it's overflowing the container. See here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7lmks1wo6e2qajx/Screenshot%202016-11-02%2014.50.14.png?dl=0

If you add `overflow: hidden` to `.categories` you can see the problem not occurring.